# java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/BeanManager'

Tags: jsf, glassfish-3, cdi, omnifaces

After build a lot of converters in my JSF app, I turned my attention to Omnifaces and everything's working like a charm. The problem arises when I deploy my application. The first time I access to my login page, it throws the next exception:

```
    SEVERE: BeanManager enum singleton failed to initialize.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/BeanManager' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Error retrieving java:comp/BeanManager [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve bean manager]]
            at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:87)
            at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.init(BeanManager.java:76)
            at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.getReference(BeanManager.java:115)
            at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createValidator(OmniApplication.java:105)
            at com.sun.faces.component.validator.ComponentValidators.addValidatorsToComponent(ComponentValidators.java:280)
            at com.sun.faces.component.validator.ComponentValidators.addDefaultValidatorsToComponent(ComponentValidators.java:147)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.processValidators(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:550)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.privateOnComponentPopulated(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:531)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.MetadataHandler.apply(MetadataHandler.java:104)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:116)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:233)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:464)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:253)
            at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1333)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/BeanManager' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Error retrieving java:comp/BeanManager [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve bean manager]]
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
            at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:83)
            ... 53 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Error retrieving java:comp/BeanManager [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve bean manager]
            at org.glassfish.weld.BeanManagerNamingProxy.handle(BeanManagerNamingProxy.java:129)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.NamedNamingObjectManager.tryNamedProxies(NamedNamingObjectManager.java:89)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:174)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
            ... 57 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve bean manager
            at org.glassfish.weld.BeanManagerNamingProxy.handle(BeanManagerNamingProxy.java:119)
            ... 60 more
```

However, when I refresh my page, everything works fine.

Any ideas? Regards !!!

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with JSF 2.1

Comment: Do you have beans.xml under your WEB-INF folder?

Comment: No, I don't. I just added omnifaces-1.7.jar to my classpath, and use the converter, just like the Omnifaces showcase shows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be thrown when the webapp is not explicitly CDI-enabled while it's deployed to an implicitly CDI-enabled server (such as GlassFish 3 in your case). This is fixed since OmniFaces 1.8. An alternative is to explicitly enable CDI in your webapp by creating a `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` file.

Comment: Hey buddy.. could u look at this question. I now its not good to ask help on someone else question thread but I am in hurry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985468/jsf-access-html-element-value-in-bean-class

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exception while trying to run my Payara 4.1 application. Actually I was interchangeably getting the following 2:

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413: The bean Managed Bean [class com.baw.website.beans.quality.ui.AuditBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] declares a passivating scope but has a non-passivation-capable dependency Managed Bean [class com.baw.website.rest.clients.AuthUtil] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

and

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/BeanManager' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Error retrieving java:comp/BeanManager [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve bean manager]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:90)
```

After analyzing, I found that I had 2 classes with the same name in different packages:

com.mycompany.mypackageone.Myclass

com.mycompany.mypackagetwo.Myclass

One of them was being CDI-injected into a ManagedBean which was related to a JSF page that used Omnifaces. I'm not sure where the conflict was occurring (I do have a beans.xml). But for me, stop/starting Payara, and renaming one of the 2 identically-named classes did the trick and got rid of the errors.