# JSF onchange event

Tags: java, jquery, jsf

I have a JSF application in which I have an combobox like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
  <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    helpKey = 'APPLICATION_EDIT_DATASOURCE';

    function reapplyStyles() {}

    function selectT(data){
        if(data.status == "begin"){
            $('editForm:selectTypeButton').click();    
        }
    }

   //--><!]]>
</script>

  <h:form id="editForm">
    <h:inputHidden id="id" value="#{applicationObject.objectId}"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="type" value="#{applicationObject.object.type}"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="selectedDSForApp" value="#{applicationObject.selectedDataSourceId}"/>
    <ui:param name="activityDataSource" value="#{applicationObject.selectedDataSourceBean}"/>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="activityDataSourceRulesPanel">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="padded" rowClasses="padded">

      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.transformation_rule}"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="dsTransformationRule" value="#{activityDataSource.selectedTransformationRule}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.transformationRules}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <ui:fragment rendered="#{sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageRules')}" >
              <input type="button" value="#{msgs.button_ellipsis}" class="ruleEditorBtn"
                     onclick="SailPoint.Rule.Editor.edit($('editForm:dsTransformationRule').value,
                             'ActivityTransformer',
                             $('editForm:refreshActivityDataSourceRulesButton'))" />
          </ui:fragment>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.correlation_rule}"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="dsCorrelationRule" value="#{activityDataSource.selectedCorrelationRule}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.correlationRules}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <ui:fragment rendered="#{sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageRules')}" >
              <input type="button" value="#{msgs.button_ellipsis}" class="ruleEditorBtn"
                     onclick="SailPoint.Rule.Editor.edit($('editForm:dsCorrelationRule').value,
                             'ActivityCorrelation',
                             $('editForm:refreshActivityDataSourceRulesButton'))" />
          </ui:fragment>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.activity_data_src_type}"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="collectorSettings">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="collectorType"
                           value="#{activityDataSource.object.type}"
                           rendered="#{empty activityDataSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
                          <!--  onchange="$('editForm:selectTypeButton').click();"> -->
             <f:ajax event="change" 
                    onevent="selectT"
                    execute="@this dsTransformationRule dsCorrelationRule"
                    render="dsTransformationRule dsCorrelationRule"
                    listener="#{activityDataSource.handleCollectorTypeChange}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{msgs.select_collector_type}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.collectorTypes}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="fixedCollectorType" value="#{empty activityDataSource.object.type ? 'None' : activityDataSource.object.type}"
                           rendered="#{not empty activityDataSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="true"
                           readonly="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{empty activityDataSource.object.type ? 'None' : activityDataSource.object.type}"
                          itemLabel="#{empty activityDataSource.object.type ? msgs.none : activityDataSource.object.type}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="configSettings">
      <h:messages infoClass="formInfo" warnClass="formWarn" errorClass="formError" fatalClass="formError"/>

      <h:panelGroup  rendered="#{not empty activityDataSource.object.collector}">
        <ui:include src="#{activityDataSource.configPage}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
    <h:panelGroup>
      <div class="buttonRow">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
          <h:commandButton id="activityDataSourceSave" action="#{activityDataSource.saveAction}" value="#{msgs.button_save}" styleClass="primaryBtn"/>
        </ui:fragment>
        <h:commandButton id="activityDataSourceCancel" action="#{activityDataSource.cancelAction}" value="#{msgs.button_cancel}" styleClass="secondaryBtn"/>
      </div>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <a4j:commandButton id="refreshActivityDataSourceRulesButton"
                       style="display:none"
                       immediate="true"
                       render="activityDataSourceRulesPanel"/>

    <a4j:commandButton id="selectTypeButton" action="#{activityDataSource.selectType}" style="display:none"
                       render="configSettings, collectorSettings"
                       oncomplete="initializeSelectedConfigPage();"/>

  </h:form>
```

Bean Class

```
public String getSelectedTransformationRule() {
    if (_selectedTransformationRule == null) {
        ActivityDataSourceDTO dto = getObject();
        if (dto != null)
            _selectedTransformationRule = dto.getTransformationRule();
    }

    return _selectedTransformationRule;
}
public String getSelectedCorrelationRule() {
    if (_selectedCorrelationRule == null) {
        ActivityDataSourceDTO dto = getObject();
        if (dto != null)
            _selectedCorrelationRule = dto.getCorrelationRule();
    }

    return _selectedCorrelationRule;
}
```

In the above code I have a normal onchange event & an ajax onchange event on combobox element id= collectorType.

Is there any limitation in using two change for same element in JSF.

Also how can I merge first onchange to ajax onchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onevent` attribute of `<f:ajax>` as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="collectorType"
                   value="#{activityDataSource.object.type}"
                   rendered="#{empty activityDataSource.object.id}"
                   disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                   readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
     <f:ajax event="change" 
            execute="@this" 
            render="dsTransformationRule dsCorrelationRule"
            listener="#{activityDataSource.handleCollectorTypeChange}" 
            onevent="$('#editForm\\:selectTypeButton').click();"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{msgs.select_collector_type}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.collectorTypes}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

also notice I've modified the selector `'#editForm\\:selectTypeButton'` to escape the `:` in your button's id.

[UPDATE]

Here's what you can do to achieve the scenario we've discussed in the comments:

First to populate both `dsTransformationRule` and `dsCorrelationRule` with `_selectedTransformationRule` and `_selectedCorrelationRule` respectively, create an initialization method for them, and call it in `@PostConstruct` method ([check Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)), so in your bean class you would have something like this:

```
@PostConstuct
public void init() {
    initRules();
    //include another things you want to be initializaed when this page finishes constructing. 
}

private void initRules() {
    ActivityDataSourceDTO dto = getObject();
    if (dto == null)
        return;

    if (_selectedTransformationRule == null)
        _selectedTransformationRule = dto.getTransformationRule();

    if (_selectedCorrelationRule == null)
        _selectedCorrelationRule = dto.getCorrelationRule();
}

//Let the getters do no dto access, so it won't matter if they're called twice on change
public String getSelectedTransformationRule() {
    return _selectedTransformationRule;
}

public String getSelectedCorrelationRule() {
    return _selectedCorrelationRule;
}
```

Now your `f:ajax` can normally `execute` and `render` your select menus without fearing to access your DTO layer multiple times

```
<f:ajax event="change" onevent="selectT"
        execute="@this dsTransformationRule dsCorrelationRule"
        render="dsTransformationRule dsCorrelationRule"
        listener="#{activityDataSource.handleCollectorTypeChange}" />
```

This way, when `handleCollectorTypeChange` is invoked, will have both `_selectedTransformationRule` and `_selectedCorrelationRule` populated with their last selected values.

On a side note, if you want to get the values of select menus `dsTransformationRule` and `dsCorrelationRule` in a validation or conversion phase, or directly via an event listener method that is called before the `Update Model Values` phase, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985468/jsf-access-html-element-value-in-bean-class/23010795#23010795) that would help you reach the value from the component.

Hopefully this would solve your issue, or at least set you in the right direction.

Comment: its working. But i noticed while debugging that method in the bean related to element that I want to render are called twice. How to handle this?

Comment: @CODEFISH what is getting called twice exactly ? and what are those elements in your `render` attribute ?

Comment: I have upated my question. These 2 method in bean class class are called twice on change event.The ajax change event is in the element id=collectorType.

Comment: @CODEFISH that's expected, because you're evaluating both select menus  `dsTransformationRule` and `dsCorrelationRule` twice, in `execute` and `render`. Try using only `render` or are you expecting the values submitted from those drop downs on your ajax change event ?

Comment: Yes that what I need. I wants those two id in 'execute' to be executed first,so that they will populate & get the vale & will provide the data for the ajax call. What should i do? I am new to JSF. Basically i want on selection of collectorType combo box other two combox box i.e. dsTransformationRule & dsCorrelationRule should be populated automatically. And the value of those combobox i get from these 2 bean class method.